# Time Format in EditText

Tags: android

I'm currently having some problems in time format. I'm writing a trial program to manage my productivity as I can set my start time, stop time, find the time difference and hence calculate my work rate.

At the moment, I made 2 edittext boxes with input format as "time". several questions:

- how and in which format that I can get from the edittexts.
- how can I find the time difference (this is the consequence of the 1st question)
- is there any better way to do this since in this way, user has to know that he has to enter in a certain format.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the EditText only deals with Strings, which means that you as a developer can only read and write text from and into it.

TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME (introduces a disconnect here in the sense that it) restricts the user from entering anything but time values but you only get to read text.

You'll have to process the content yourself to interpret the date/time using the `Calendar`. DateUtils (developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) and TimeUtils (developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimeUtils.html) are useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can always deal with strings entered in EditText.But then you would have to specify what format should be followed by user and also you need to check it once user enters it.That would be a tedious process.

Also It won't be a good practice if you would use EditText for getting time values.Instead of using EditText,you should use two time pickers for getting start and stop time from user.

That way,it would be giving you values neatly and without worrying user for entering time into specific format,neither you would have to check it for correctness once it has been entered.